# Finite normal subgroups of a profinite group

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, profinite-groups

I am self studying *Profinite Groups* by Ribes and Zalesskii and I am stuck reading a proof.

> Let $G$ be a profinite group and $H \unlhd G$ a closed normal
> subgroup. If $H$ is **finite** then there exists $U \unlhd G$ open normal
> subgroup such that $U \cap H = 1$.

(This is the first passage in the proof that every epimorphism between profinite groups admits a section, page 29 in my edition)

As this is presented as a fact I think I am missing something easy, however I can't seem to prove it. I tried to reason in the case where all the groups are finite with the discrete topology, but then the assertion seems false: if $G$ is a finite $p$-group and $H = Z(G)$ then for each nontrivial normal subgroup $N \unlhd G$ we have $H \cap N \neq 1$.

What am I missing here?

Comment: In the case of finite groups  you did not include the option that $N$ is trivial: in a finite group, the trivial subgroup is open!

Comment: @KCd Oooh that's right! The case in which $G$ is finite is settled then.

Comment: I guess I'm very late, but I'll try to answer. Suppose $H = \{1,g_1,\ldots,g_n\}$. Since $G$ is profinite, you know that $\cap U = \{1\}$, that is, for each $1\leq i \leq n$, you can find $U_i$ such that $g_i \notin U_i$. Thus, if you take $V = \cap_{i=1}^{n} U_i$, you have an open normal subgroup such that $H \cap V = \{1\}$.